# Edit excel file locally based on remote host condition ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to update a XLSX file locally using this module : https://github.com/mohameosam/open_excel

I have succeed to update the XLSX file when running a task without "Conditional Variables". But when I try to run it with "When" variable. It shows error below :

> TASK [Update predepchk] ****************************************************************************
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (open_excel) module: when Supported parameters include: attributes, backup, cell_style, content, delimiter, dest, directory_mode, follow, force, group, index_by_name, mode, op, owner, read_range, regexp, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, sheet_name, src, unsafe_writes, updates_matrix"}

Here is my ansible yml file :

```js
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Ping all hosts
      ping:
    - name: Print a message
      debug:
        msg: 'All set'
    - name: Show facts available on the system
      ansible.builtin.debug:
              var: ansible_facts
- name: PredepCHK
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:  
     - name: Update predepchk
       open_excel:
          src: "/root/Documents/Ansible/XLSX/predepchk.xlsx"
          dest: "/root/Documents/Ansible/XLSX/predepchk_updated.xlsx"
          sheet_name: "predepchk"
          op: "w"
          updates_matrix: "{{ [{'cell_row': 21, 'cell_col': 1, 'cell_value': 1}] }}"
          when: ansible_facts['distribution'] == "Debian" and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "9"
```

My question will be:
Can I pass this remote host condition to my local tasks?

Comment: You have an indentation typo. `when:` should be at the same level as `open_excel`

Comment: This is a typical case where you should have deleted the question yourself as it will anyway be closed as "caused by a typo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by @Zeitounator .

It's because I have my `when:` conditional statement where was not the same level as `"name: / open_excel:"`